# Cant read value in DB or its different from mention

Tags: php, database

Im new in Php. I have tried everything to make it work. So now i give up and would like to ask anyone who know the problem.

First of all, Im have this code below.

```
<?php

if ($chkadmin->info['crowdflower'] != 'enable') {
exit(  );
}

$q = $db->query( 'SELECT * FROM crowdflower_settings' );



if ($r = $db->fetch_array( $q )) {
$crowdflower[$r['field']] = $r['value'];
}

$payload = $input->p['payload'];

$signature = $input->p['signature'];


if ($input->g['i'] == 'start') {
sha1( $payload . $crowdflower['key'] );
$hash = '';

    $details = json_decode( $payload );
    $crowdflower_currency = $crowdflower['credit_type'];
    $userid = $details->uid;

    $membershipid = $db->fetchOne('SELECT type FROM members WHERE id=' . $userid );

    $membership = $db->fetchRow('SELECT crowdflower_ratio, crowdflower_points FROM membership WHERE id=' . $membershipid );

    $user_earn = $details->adjusted_amount * $membership['crowdflower_ratio'];
    $site_reward = $details->amount * 0.0100000000000000002081668;

    $data = array( 'date' => TIMENOW, 'user_id' => $details->uid, 'trackid' => $details->job_title, 'task' => $details->job_id, 'reward' => $details->adjusted_amount, 'reward_usd' => $site_reward, 'user_reward' => $user_earn );
    $db->insert( 'crowdflower_postback', $data );
    $testid = $db->lastInsertId();

    echo $testid;
    exit();

}


if ($input->g['i'] == 'finish') {
$details = json_decode( $payload );

$crowdflower_currency = $crowdflower['credit_type'];

$userid = $db->fetchOne('SELECT user_id FROM crowdflower_postback WHERE id=' . $details->conversion_id );

$membershipid = $db->fetchOne('SELECT type FROM members WHERE id=' . $userid );

$membership = $db->fetchRow('SELECT crowdflower_ratio, crowdflower_points FROM membership WHERE id=' . $membershipid );

$user_earn = $details->adjusted_amount * $membership['crowdflower_ratio'];
$site_reward = $details->amount * 0.0100000000000000002081668;
$data = array( 'date' => TIMENOW, 'trackid' => $details->job_title, 'task' => $details->job_id, 'reward' => $details->adjusted_amount, 'reward_usd' => $site_reward, 'user_reward' => $user_earn, 'status' => 'Completed' );
$db->update( 'crowdflower_postback', $data,  'id=' . $details->conversion_id );

if ($crowdflower_currency == 'money') {
    $points = $membership['crowdflower_points'];

    $db->query('UPDATE members SET money=money+' . $user_earn . ' WHERE id=' . $userid );
}
else {
    $points = $membership['crowdflower_points'] + $user_earn;
}

addpoints( $userid, $points );
echo 'OK';
exit(  );
}

?>
```

But the

```
$db->query('UPDATE members SET money=money+' . $user_earn . ' WHERE id=' . $userid );
```

is not updated. If i remove

```
if ($crowdflower_currency == 'money') {
}
```

the code is working. Its seem like 'money' is not exist or different from my database. But when i check in my database, the text 'money' is exist. Where the problem actually?

Comment: Have you tried executing the statement in sql only, without php? Also, have you checked your $crowdflower_currency variable?

Comment: did you bother checking what value is in `$crowdflower_currency`? e.g. `var_dump($crowdflower_currency)`?

Comment: My guess is that instead of `if ($r = $db->fetch_array( $q )) {`, you probably want `while ($r = $db->fetch_array( $q )) {` (up towards the top of your code).

Comment: @MarcB checked. Its didnt show anything.

Comment: well if `$crowdflower_currency` is empty, you must realise that's the problem.

Comment: @Dagon yup you right. empty value. That the problem actually. Now its solved.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$q = $db->query( 'SELECT * FROM crowdflower_settings' );` most likely returns multiple rows, you want to iterate through all of them, not just look at the first.

Your current code ...

```
if ($r = $db->fetch_array( $q )) {
    $crowdflower[$r['field']] = $r['value'];
}
```

... will only assign the key and value from the first row.

Instead, you want to do this ...

```
while ($r = $db->fetch_array( $q )) {
    $crowdflower[$r['field']] = $r['value'];
}
```

... to loop through each row and add each key and value onto the `$crowdflower` array.